# Change page up / page down speed or disable animation?

Tags: safari, macos, web-browser, keybindings, animation

I do a lot of scrolling in Safari. I often end up hitting space bar to jump across just the right sized blocks. I just looked into it now and I wonder, is it the exact same action as page down? Anyhow. I have a sort of vision problem and the aggressive animation in the scrolling action is quite overwhelming. **Is there any workaround for disabling it so hitting space bar or pg up/down would still scroll that perfect amount of the page, but bypass that whole visual effect?**

On another note, even just knowing **what the numeric value of that perfect step actually is**, might be helpful in coming up with something. If it gets assigned by monitor size, being a fluid concept, that's another thing of course.

Comment: Yes, they both move the same amount. They depend on your window size though.

Comment: Apparently the amount of scrolling is not a fixed value: it's "100% of your resolution-specific viewpoint, minus 2em", em being a typographical unit for currently specified type, meaning that the press of space bar / page down scrolls down one page's worth minus two rows of text, whichever the font, its size and your reso. If I'm not wrong, this is css code, meaning that this feature is in Safari, not global Mac OS? If so, the format of that scroll amount doesn't ring any more bells for me because I've never even heard of modifying browser behavior by touching... css code? Back to question 1.

Comment: I don't know that it uses CSS itself, but it does seem to use the same units. And yes, that would mean that the feature is implemented in Safari specifically.